# Level of award - International/Institutional

Tags: application, funding, postdocs

I'm writing a Postdoctoral fellowship application. There is an online form to fill out and for each award I have received and I need to indicate the 'level' of the award. The options are Institutional, National or International.

Is an award which can be applied to by anyone worldwide but is only tenable at a particular institution an institutional or international award? For example: [Gates Cambridge](http://www.gatescambridge.org).

The fellowship documentation does not provide a definition. Is there a generally accepted definition for the level of an award?

Comment: I would interpret these levels as referring to who is eligible to receive the award. That is, if the award is only for people at your institution, then it's an institutional award; if everyone in your country is eligible, then it's a national award; and if everyone in the world is eligible, then it's international.

Answer (score 2):

The standard definition, in my experience is if an award is only available to individuals at/applying to a specific single institution, it is institutional. If the award is only available to individuals in/applying to a particular country it is national, regardless of citizenship requirements. If the award can be used at any institution in any country it is a international award, again regardless of citizenship requirements.

The [Gates Cambridge](https://www.gatescambridge.org/apply/eligibility) fellowship is open to anyone, but can only be used at Cambridge and is therefore a national award.